# SSRS Report Server showing anomalous data

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, power-bi-report-server, reportserver

I have deployed SSRS Report on report server (production environment). I have set a Date parameter which refreshes the data of the report on that particular date.(There is no default value set for the parameter)
The underlying data is pulling from SQL tables which are updated overnight so that data is not changing in-between refreshes.

When I refresh the data , The figures gets doubled on some cells and a 0 on some other cells of the report.
Initially it took 2 to 3 refreshes to get the figure I was expecting but then I just kept refreshing to see how many times it would take to get that figure again and it took 3 to 4 times of refreshes.

It is really strange behaviour of the report server. However, If I refresh that same report on the ssrs, I get expected figures on every refresh which I really expect report server to do so the same when I upload report file to report server via report server manager.

This needs to be solved to avoid people loosing faith in the service.
Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Have you checked the caching properties of he report from the server? make sure its one "Always run this report with the most recent data".

Comment: Yes. I have checked every caching property that I know of. It is set to Always run this report with the most recent data. Still the problem persists